# Using Javascript to create SVG / canvas sketches with comic style / hand jitter

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

How to create SVG / canvas sketches with comic style / hand jitter using Javascript

I am aware of the [xkcd](http://bl.ocks.org/dfm/3914862) style JS plotter and of [this](http://29a.ch/2010/2/10/hand-drawn-lines-algorithm-javascript-canvas-html5) article.
Note that I am not asking for plots, but for any kind of sketching, lines, shapes, text and so on.

What further methods / technologies exist using JS?

EDIT: After having thought and read some time about this I decided to implement my own JS library providing cartoon style drawing for SVG and HTML5 canvas. 
It is called `comic.js` and can be found [here](https://github.com/balint42/comic.js).

Comment: no - I mean to programmatically draw using commands like "line", "circle", ...

Comment: Have you seen this post? It walks through several canvas techniques http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's definitely a good article and I am sure one could find some inspiration where to start - but it does not really seem to cover my goal.

Comment: Well, first you need to find a way to draw primitive shapes using a step by step algorithm that draws lines - e.g draw a circle by adjusting the angle while drawing a line. Then it would be easier to adjust the procedure to include random up/down/left/right movements. Your question is not really how to draw jittered lines, it is how to draw shapes manually, without using circle,arc commands. That should be your starting point IMO.

Comment: If I rephrase my question to ask what JS libraries exist at all that allow native comic style drawing, will you re-open the question?
Please note that I would _not_ ask for "best practice" or "recommendations" but for mere existence of any JS lib - and there should be very few if any at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be using a Canvas library to do that, just for the sake of simplicity when it comes to manipulating shapes.

The ones I would look for are [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#importsvg-svg) and [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/). 
However, I will focus on Paper.js because it is the one I worked with.

---

- You can [draw beziers or lines](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/working-with-path-items/) to create the shapes. You can even
  [import SVG's](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#importsvg-svg) if you want. You can even have predefined shapes
  such as [Circles/Squares](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/creating-predefined-shapes/) etc.

**So you have the shapes, now what?**

- You can [flatten](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#flatten-maxDistance) them(*subdivide them into segments, adding more
  vertices to their geometry*). You can increase the subdivision
  interval which would result in high number of vertices/nodes per
  path. Subdivision interval is the parameter `maxDistance` of the
  `flatten` function.
- Then you can walk along the vertices of each path/shape and move each
  one by a certain degree(e.g 1-2 pixels to a random direction), by using `position.x` and `position.y`

**If this is what you mean:**

[image: Jittered Shape through Curve Subdivision. a jsFiddle screenshot]

, **then here is the code** :

```
//STEP 1 -- create shapes, a circle and rectangle in this example

var myCircle = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50);
myCircle.strokeColor = 'white';
myCircle.strokeWidth = 2;

var mySquare =  new Rectangle(new Point(350, 250), new Point(190, 100));
var square = new Path.Rectangle(mySquare);
square.strokeColor = 'white';
square.strokeWidth = 2;

//STEP 2 -- Subdivide the shapes into segments. Parameter here is the max distance we walk along-the-path before adding a new vertex

myCircle.flatten(5);
square.flatten(4);


//STEP 3 -- Loop through the segment points of the path and move each to a random value between 1 and 4

for (var i = 0; i < myCircle.segments.length; i++) { //loop for circle
   myCircle.segments[i].point.x += getRandomInt(1,3);
   myCircle.segments[i].point.y += getRandomInt(1,3);
};

for (var i = 0; i < square.segments.length; i++){ //loop for square
   square.segments[i].point.x += getRandomInt(1,3);
   square.segments[i].point.y += getRandomInt(1,3);
};


//draw the paper view
view.draw();


//Utility function that returns a random integer within a range
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

**and this is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r12vaw95/7/) for it**:

---

The issue with this scenario is that each 'point' on your canvas is an object and the high number of points/nodes/vertices is a bit heavy for the browser to handle. So this might be an obstacle if your designs are complex and/or you want to have the user interact with your drawings(the interaction might prove sluggish).

Alternatively you can use plain-old canvas to do this, without any libraries but I wouldn't do that since I smell the need for algorithms to draw the shapes manually, then introduce jitter in those algorithms. This would be much faster, *in terms of computation time*, but it would be harder to implement since Canvas is a low-level kind of thing - it only remembers pixels drawed on and you would need to roll-your-own data structures to remember the shapes, their positions etc etc..

Comment: Since my question got blocked and this is the only answer I accepted it. Thanks for writing this up, I agree it's a possible way. I think however that if one uses existing drawing libs, then it should be considered to abstract the "comicification" away from any specific lib: writing a lib that takes nodes in a general format and introduces comic noise and gives them back.

Comment: yeah that sounds pretty cool. If I had more time I'd write up a function that extends the starting/closing segments of the path just a little bit, so as to look more *comified*, using your terminology. The library is easy to build if you are working with `SVG paths` since they already contain nodes and are indeed vector shapes by nature. Canvas however would require a library that already mimics vector shape fundamentals such as nodes, which would be harder to build, if we are talking about a solution similar to the one proposed above.

Comment: so basically I implemented what we have been talking about - take a look at my link above :)